# Changing the pictures after seconds in android

Tags: android

Here is my main activity-after `OnCreate` code is  :

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

and I have one `ImageView` so I can show the url-picture in this `ImageView` with below code:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute("http://url.com/background1.jpg");
```

what i need exactly, i need to add three image in this `ImageView` and in every 3 seconds, picture automatically changed to another link.
`Picture 2` and after three second, `Picture 3`

How we can do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Timer` , `CountDownTimer` or `Handler` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to change image after 3 sec

call this in your `OnCreate()`

```
  handler=new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 3000);
```

define it outside the `OnCreate()`

```
private Runnable myRunnable=new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
 // change your url to imgeview here some thing like
 new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute("http://url.com/picutre2.jpg");
      handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
}
```

**Note :**   my suggestions is to cache the downloaded image so to avoid network usage

Comment: You must create it,  as Runnable object